# VB asp.net set result of a control to a variable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

trying to set the result of dropdownlist to a variable but having great troubles.

```
    Sub OutageSource(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Year.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim year As Integer


    year = year.SelectedValue

    MsgBox(year)

    End Sub

     <asp:DropDownList ID="Year" runat="server" onChange = "" Width="70px">
                    <asp:ListItem Value=1988>1988</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem Value=1987>1987</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

So im trying to get year var in the vb section equal to the selected year in the page.
Im used to VBA so perhaps theres something im missing?

Cheers ty

Comment: it says 'SelectedValue' is not a member of 'Integer'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just copied your code into a VS2008 demo, and it seems that VB.NET's case (de)sensitivity is the problem (at least in my case - no pun intended). VB.NET doesn't see a difference in the `year` variable, and the `Year` variable, and assumes the former since you declared it locally to the Sub.

Try calling the local variable `intYear` and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Your `year` variable has the same name as the control.
You can either change the name or write `Me.Year` to refer to the control.

Comment: I tried the me.year and it gave me the following, Property access must assign to the property or use its value.

Comment: After changign the var name , i keep getting System.ArgumentException: Argument 'Prompt' cannot be converted to type 'String'. anyway to set the control to a string or integer type?

Comment: You cannot call `MsgBox` on the server (although that's not what the error is).  You need to use Javascript.